# Source Maps don't seem to be working for production bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, production-environment, source-maps

I'm creating sourcemaps through Webpack by using `devtool: 'source-map'`. When I create my production build, I get a folder structure like this:

```
.
├── index.html
└── static
    ├── bundle.js
    ├── bundle.js.map
    ├── style.css
    └── style.css.map
```

However, when I run the production build, the error in the console shows up like this:

[image]

Why does the error message just say `bundle.js:1`? If I click the `Sources` tab in the dev tools, it does say `Source Map Detected`, however that's all it does:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing? Am I supposed to set up anything else further or what? Any help would be appreciated!